# How can i use ngModel and value both in a input angular 7

Tags: angular

```
<input type="text" value="{{listData.minPrice}}" [('ngModel')]="test.minPrice" name="minPrice" >
```

How can I show minPrice in my text box and also on fetch its updated value for saving.

Comment: you shouldn't need to ever use both of them. `ngModel` sets the value of the input...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NgModel` means 2 way data binding. Moreover, if the value of your input is changed by user, the variable also changes, if the value of your variable changes, the value of input is also changes.

Then,

You don't need to bind `value` and `ngModel` together. It must be like the following;

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="test.minPrice" name="minPrice" >
```

On ts file, if you update `test.minPrice` variable, value of input is updates automatically.